# Factory reset in phones that don't support SD-cards

Tags: factory-reset, external-sd, internal-sd

Does factory reset on a phone without SD-card support delete the files stored in the ExternalStorageDirectory?

Explanation : Say I have a device like the Galaxy S or an iPhone(I know, sacrilege) both devices don't support SD-cards(Not sure about Galaxy S, definitely about the iPhone). My question is if such a device which doesn't support SD-cards is factory reset, then do your files and media stored in this device's "External Storage Directory" which actually happens to be on the phone get deleted?

My guess is no, am I right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct.

The external storage directory is classed as an 'External SDCard'. Anything with SDCard in the title **is not** wiped during a factory reset.

When you go to factory reset, you will be given the option to wipe your SDCard as well as the internal storage data directory.