# My Android phone is completely reset, whats the best way to recover the deleted data?

Tags: factory-reset, data-recovery, motorola-moto-g

A person at a phone store reset all the contents of my Motorola Moto G Android phone, and I did not give them permission to do so. I had many important pictures and videos, but the even more important thing were the audio recordings I had created.

Is there ANY WAY to recover this data? I know it was reset, but I'm very stressed and would appreciate a pointer of a way to effectively recover some or all of the data without comprising it in the process. I am not using the phone, and had shut it off entirely. I'm aware that the more you use it, the more it overwrites the data. I NEVER had a backup, dumb, I know.

Thank you folks!

**Edit: I recovered most of my photos and videos just now through Google+, most of it was synced! But how can I recover my voice recordings ? That's what's most important to me. I used this app. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.andrwq.recorder&hl=en

Unfortunately, my phone model never supported SD cards, so there's nothing there.

Comment: When I said "without comprising it the process", I meant the data. I could care less about the phone, even if it meant tearing the whole thing apart!

Comment: If you asked to have your phone repaired at the official customer service, there is a possibility that the device was replaced by entirely new device, so there wouldn't be any trace of the old data. I assumed the pictures, videos and audio recordings were saved on "external" storage, so it should be there, [unless they decided to reset the SD Card too, for whatever reason](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/37530/). However, it'd be [hard to recover the data after factory reset](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/49888/)

Comment: Unfortunately, it never came with an SD card slot, this is the 1st gen moto g. @AndrewT. What about the reset recovery software options?

Comment: It's the same phone, btw.

Comment: If it's not possible whatsoever, what is this article based on? http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/stop-thieves-recovering-data-factory-reset/ @AndrewT.

Comment: I just checked my Google+ online, and all the photos are there from the phone!!! @AndrewT. but the voice recordings... is there any way I could retrieve those?

Comment: But how can I recover my voice recordings ? That's what's most important to me. I used this app. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.andrwq.recorder&hl=en

Comment: I understand Moto G doesn't have physical SD card, but it emulates the SD card inside the phone, which seems to be cleared due to the reset. Also, I didn't say it's impossible, but it's hard to recover the data as is. You could try to find a recovery tool as mentioned in that site, but there is no guarantee it will restore the data 100%. Fortunately, the pictures and videos are synced (read: "backed-up"), but I doubt the app has synced feature, which I couldn't really help. Maybe other readers here can help you... sorry.

Answer (score 7):

There isn't an easy way, but still, it might be possible. The keyword to it is [File carving](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_carving) (find some more links on this topic in our [data-recovery tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/data-recovery/info)).

**Make sure to not have any modifications/changes going on on your device, or at least as few as possible!** Each change (written file etc.) lowers your chances of a successful recovery.

A crucial pre-condition to this is either a rooted device, or a custom recovery.

- With a custom recovery: Take a [nandroid](/questions/tagged/nandroid) backup
- With a rooted device: create images from your storage

For manual image creation, you'd first need to figure where the partitions are that you need. Your data is usually stored in two places: the `/data` partition, and your SD card(s). Let's find where they are:

- connect to your device via [adb](/questions/tagged/adb) (follow up to the [adb tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/adb/info) for details if you're not familiar with this) using `adb shell`
- execute the `mount` command
- in the output, look for the corresponding entries to `/data` and your SD cards
- take a note of the corresponding device entries (usually starting with `/dev/`)

At this point it would be helpful to have an empty *external* SD card:

- still connected via `adb shell`, get root access by executing `su`
- run `dd if=<data-dev> of=/sdcard/data.img` (replacing `<data-dev>` with the device of your `/data` partition), repeat similarly for your internal SD card
- exit `adb shell` (simply type `exit` and hit the return key)
- pull the files to your computer using `adb pull /sdcard/data.img data.img`, or connect the card using a card-reader to access them directly from your computer

If you don't have an external SD card, but have a Linux computer available (I cannot say whether it works on Windows as well, but it should at least on a Mac), you can instead try the following:

`adb shell "stty raw; cat <data-dev>" > data.img`

This would create the image files directly on your computer.

Now, once you've got the image files on your computer, you can examine their contents using some forensics software. [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) would be a suitable tool, and is available for free, plus runs on most major systems. For details on this, you might wish to check [One Way to Use a Linux Computer to Recover Files from an Android Device](http://www.df.lth.se/~jokke/androidfilerecovery/). The *TestDisk* Wiki (see previous link) also includes several articles on how to recover deleted files.