# Is all data lost after factory reset?

Tags: recovery-mode, factory-reset, data-recovery

I had an LG Optimus I phone (LG E410f) with Android (can't remember the exact version now, but I *believe* it was 4.1.2) -- and I had [OI Notepad](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.openintents.notepad) pp installed  (app home is [here](http://www.openintents.org/notepad/)). There were some *very* important notes saved on that notepad, but I accidentally did a factory reset while trying to boot into recovery (as far as I remember I did boot into recovery, but now everytime I boot it, the phone will start the initial setup again). I did not finish the initial setup after the accidental factory reset, so as to not overwrite any data in case it's possible to recover.

The device was rooted prior to booting into recovery (but I did not install alternative recovery/os/anything -- I just used some apps that needed root access).

So, my question is: is there any way to recover the app data?

Comment: Did you just *boot into* recovery – or did you perform any actions there? Just booting into recovery mode doesn't change (or delete) your data. Next time you boot up the device normally, you should find it as you've left it.

Comment: Every time I boot, it behaves as it would start setting up the phone for the first time again (asks for Google account, etc). I dit not proceed any further (didn't set up the Google account).

Comment: That's a complete different issue then. Looks like your device does a factory-reset either on startup or on shutdown. I vaguely remember we've had a related question already.

Comment: Ok -- I did search a bit and found this question: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/89777/my-android-phone-is-completely-reset-whats-the-best-way-to-recover-the-deleted Is it that one? (I really think I rebooted into recovery, but if you say it's factory reset, then I'll take a lok into that)

Comment: No, that's not the one. The one I think of was about a device resetting itself on every boot. Bot just booting into recovery doesn't trigger that.

Comment: I edited my question -- including the title -- since it seems that a factory reset was performed.

Comment: If you really performed a factory reset, data recovery won't be easy. Please see our [data-recovery tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/data-recovery/info) and the questions linked from there.

Comment: Thanks! I took a look at that page, but  I don't know how to transfer the data out of the device without overwriting it. Can I finish the initial setup process, and then use adb to transfer an image? Wouldn't that be risky?

Comment: Each new write lowers chances of restore, of course. I'd rather boot into a custom recovery and try creating an image from there (writing it to the external SD card).

Comment: But I suppose I can't boot into custom recovery if I never actually installed one, right?

Comment: Depends. `fastboot boot recovery.img` works for some (temporarily booting the provided image without installing it).

Comment: I think I found a way. I can boot into recovery mode by holding volume-UP and plugging the USB cable. I tested, and it works (and I can get a shell through adb, *and* -- su works and I get root access). So now I should just dd the partitions to an external SD card, and start file carving on them, I believe. I'll tell later if it worked!

Comment: Sound promising! Pointer: [One Way to Use a Linux Computer to Recover Files from an Android Device](http://dflund.se/~jokke/androidfilerecovery/) uses this approach.

Comment: I got the images, and a preliminary (and naive) grep on the image seems to indicate that the data is still there!

Answer (score 3):

You might have a chance via a custom recovery:

1. boot into [recovery-mode](/questions/tagged/recovery-mode) and see if `adb devices` shows your device
2. if not, or if you have no custom recovery, you can "temporarily load one" using `fastboot boot recovery.img` (this is not guaranteed to work with all combinations, but I had luck with this using [twrp](/questions/tagged/twrp) on several devices)
3. if it shows up, use `adb shell` to get to its prompt. This should be a root prompt.
4. use `dd` to create an image of the relevant partitions (the `/data` partition is what you're usually after). Have it created on your ***external*** SD card.
5. use `adb pull` to get the image to your computer
6. use a file-carving software (see our [data-recovery tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/data-recovery/info)) to get back your deleted content from that image

Detailed information can be found in the article [One Way to Use a Linux Computer to Recover Files from an Android Device](http://dflund.se/~jokke/androidfilerecovery/) – including those for some of the tricky parts: how to find your partition (step 4), plus an alternative way to grab it (`adb shell su -c "cat /dev/block/mmcblk0" | pv > mmcblk0.raw` would work even if you have no external SD card, and write the image directly to your Linux machine).

If you got no Linux machine, there are several LiveCDs available you could use. To use ADB on those, see our [adb tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/adb/info) for a minimal installation; I'd recommend to simply download the minimalist archive [from my site](https://android.izzysoft.de/downloads), unpack to an empty directory, and run it from there.

Answer (score 1):

If the data was not encrypted and not over written, it is technically possible to recover the data using (linux) data recovery tools.

It will require a root shell, it can be the one of your main system, one from the recovery system or one from a volatile system you would load from a computer using fastboot binary.

You may want to check if you didn't just cleared dalvik cache.

If adb is enabled on your recovery or volatile system, you can explore the file system to check if the application folder is still there.