# How do I recover my data,? please help!

Tags: data-recovery

What basically is I have ZTE ZMAX pro , and now I have factory reset it accidentally. All my pics and videos deleted.
I want to recover them at any cost.
I don't want to overwrite anything , so that my possibility of getting recovery of data decrease.

How do I recover, plz help,

Comment: Did you used back up & sync on Google Account / Photos..? If so you can sync those from the cloud again using your google account.

Comment: Have you checked with our [data-recovery tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/data-recovery/info) already? As this is a quite frequent issue, we've collected some first-aid and links there. Also see [other questions using this tag](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-recovery), especially [My Android phone is completely reset, whats the best way to recover the deleted data?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/89777/16575)